# SFMC landing page - pull tracking via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, landing-page

I am building a dashboard to display page visits vs. conversions and have found no way to gather the page visits info directly from SFMC system. I have been looking all over the place to find a way to access this information, and the only way I can find is by pulling a report - which does not help me.

I checked dataviews and none seem to be related to web or microsites. I checked and could not find any objects to pull from on this. There is a LandingPage object, but it doesn't really seem to apply to this need at all.

I know I can use Google Analytics or similar tools to easily do this, but I need the data to stick to a single, secure source (SFMC). I know that SFMC collects this info and has it available, I just do not see how to access it.

Is this even possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [Microsite Tracking Report](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/reports/microsite_tracking_report/), but I don't think you can pull any of that data via API.

If you want something beyond that, you'll have to write it yourself in AMPScript and/or SSJS.  You can write data to Data Extensions and then retrieve with the API several ways.

Our team has done that for a client in the past. While it produced page view and link tracking desired, the overhead from the scripting caused the pages to load  was terribly slow.

Comment: dang - i was hoping I was mistaken and there was some ability hidden somewhere that I missed. Thanks Adam!